# When does the set of Frobenius conjugacy classes happen to be the whole infinite Galois group?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $ K$ be a number field and let $S$ be a finite set of places that contains the archimedean places. Let $G_{K,S}=\operatorname{Gal}(K_{S}/K)$ be the Galois group for a maximal extension $K_S/K$ unramified outside $S$. Then Chebotarev density theorem implies that the set of Frobenious conjugacy classes $\mathrm{Frob}_v$ for all $v\notin  S$ is dense in $G_{K,S}$ with respect to the Krull topology. Basically, the proof is as follows: it suffices to show that every element in every finite quotient $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ of $G_{K,S}$ is a Frobenius element, and Chebotarev density theorem shows even more: every element of $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ is a Frobenius element relative to infinitely many places of $K$ unramified in $L$. In particular, for any Galois extension $L/K$ (possibly infinite extension) which is unramified outside $S$, the set of Frobenius conjugacy classes $\mathrm{Frob}_v$ is dense in $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$.
My question is the following:

> For an infinite Galois extension $L/K$, when does the set of Frobenius conjugacy classes $\mathrm{Frob}_v$ happen to be the whole Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$, i.e. $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)=\bigcup_{v\notin S} \mathrm{Frob}_v$?

Of course, it's not true in general. But perhaps it holds for some special case. For example, what about the case assuming that $L/K$ is tamely ramified at any $v\in S$? On the other hand, maybe we can use some effective version of Chebotarev density theorem assuming the Generalized Riemann hypothesis to deduce some cases with affirmative answers. Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is NO. It is proved that any profinite group with countably many conjugacy classes must be finite, cf. [Jaikin-Zapirain A, Nikolov N. An infinite compact Hausdorff group has uncountably many conjugacy classes. Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society. 2019 Sep;147(9):4083-9.]